# LINQ query to get an object from nested collection

Tags: linq

Suppose you have a collection of collection 
Eg : CEO-> Vps-> GMs ->.. 
CEO will contain collection of VP's, VP's will have collection of GM's and so on. 
Suppose you need to find a particular GM is the alias is given. Write a linq query to get the employee details if the employee alias is given.

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you show us some code samples you are working with?

Comment: I tried to use SelectMany in linq,  var c1 = v.SelectMany(c => c)
                    .Select(c => c).ToList();
But this doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like below

```
namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CeoCollection myCEOs = new CeoCollection();

            var myGM = myCEOs.SelectMany(a => a.DummyVps.SelectMany(b => b.DummyGms.FindAll(c => c.Alias == "VeryDumb")));
        }
    }

    public abstract class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Alias { get; set; }
    }

    public class CeoCollection : List<Ceo> { }
    public class Ceo : Employee
    {
        public VpCollection DummyVps { get; set; }
    }

    public class VpCollection : List<Vp> { }
    public class Vp : Employee
    {
        public GmCollection DummyGms { get; set; }
    }

    public class GmCollection : List<Gm> { }
    public class Gm : Employee
    {

    }
}
```